# What does the x86-64 instruction "shrb %dil" mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I know that `shrb` stands for shift logical right. Usually it's used with two arguments, `shrb amount, %register`. However, in the code I'm looking at it does not use a shift amount - there is just a register specified:

```
shrb %dil
```

where `%dil` stands for the lower least significant byte of `%rdi`.

Now does the command above imply that we shift right by 1? How would you go about finding this out? Is there a way to execute the command somehow and see what happens? The documentation wasn't helpful about providing information about what happens when one omits the shift amount: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf

Comment: Why on earth would you use an oracle document. Try the official intel one, or the one for your assembler. Yeah, it's `1` by default, and yeah you can stick it into a program and run it in a debugger to see what it does. Also, chances are a disassembler will show the implicit `1` too.

Comment: This instruction is synonymous with the dill weed instruction. It is designed to pickle your program

Comment: There is no such instruction on x86. It must be a macro or something proprietary to the particular assembler.

Comment: @Henrik it is at&t syntax

Comment: @Jester Meaning what?

Comment: x86 assembler mnemonics come in two flavors, intel and at&t. at&t uses instruction suffixes, and so `shrb` is just `shr` with byte operand.

Comment: @Jester If you write shr al, 1 then you can see that it's a byte operand, and if you write shr rax, 1 you see that it's not. So why shrb? Is al implicit then? Doesn't correspond to anything in hardware.

Comment: It's optional when it can be deduced from the operand. If you have a memory operand it can't be.

Comment: @Henrik IMO the AT&T (gas) syntax is designed to be easier to parse by machine - like for example the subtle difference between using immediate or memory address as source value, which is hard to read by human (missing the `[mem]` brackets of Intel syntax), but machine parser will correctly switch logic according to the first control character of the source (can't even recall now, how the immediate is marked, `#`? Something like that). So I always wonder why some people actually use it to write Assembly by hand, probably a habit.

Comment: @Ped7g The symbol for the immediate is `$` in AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 6):

This is AT&T/GAS syntax, which is very different from Intel syntax. In Intel syntax, the equivalent instruction would be:

```
shr  dil, 1
```

It is 64-bit long mode code that shifts the lowest 8 bits of the `edi` register (referred to using the `dil` mnemonic) right by 1 bit. The least significant bit (of the destination operand) is shifted into the carry flag (`CF`), and the most significant bit is cleared. (Standard behavior for `shr`.)

Notice that, in your code, the `shr` mnemonic is suffixed with a `b`. This indicates that it is a `b`yte-sized operation. Whereas Intel syntax uses annotations on one of the operands (*e.g.*, `DWORD PTR`) to disambiguate, AT&T syntax uses instruction suffixes: `b` for byte, `w` for word, `l` for long-word, `q` for quad-word, etc.

In this case, the `b` suffix is actually optional, even in AT&T syntax, since the destination operand being an 8-bit register makes the instruction unambiguous. However, Gnu tools will generally add the suffixes to all instructions for consistency, even where there is no ambiguity. This is probably where the code you have came from.

Also, in AT&T syntax, the `shr`, `sar`, and `shl` instructions often omit the shift amount when it is 1. In other words, it would be technically correct to write this as:

```
shrb  $1, %dil
```

but most tools that I've seen won't use this form, especially the Gnu disassemblers. (Notice here another difference between AT&T and Intel syntax: the destination and source operands are *reversed*.)

The omission of the shift amount when it is 1 may be for historical reasons. There are actually three different encodings for each of the shift instructions on x86: one that shifts by a constant 1, one that shifts by an immediate, and one that shifts by the contents of the `cl` register. The shift-by-immediate encoding wasn't introduced until the 286, which is why there is a separate (shorter) encoding for shift-by-1. Nowadays, you could encode shift-by-1 as shift-by-immediate-1, but no sane assembler would do that. Still, the AT&T/GAS syntax preserves this historical legacy in the notation.